# After Firebase deploy - Error: cannot find module

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, npm-install

Running a Node.js function in the local Firebase server does not result in the error below, but when I do `firebase deploy` and try to run the same function on the deployed server I get this error in the Firebase Functions log (in the web Firebase console):

`Error: Cannot find module '@google-cloud/speech'`

What have I missed? (I can run some other functions on the deployed server, but I am new to this and have no idea if I have done something different, or if there is something different about this npm module.)

Comment: What does your package.json look like?  Have you installed that module?

Comment: @DougStevenson Hm, good question. I can't find the package in package.json, but I believe I have installed it. I have done `npm install --save @google-cloud/speech` as the instructions say. I just did it once more just to be sure. And. That fixed the problem. It looks like I did not run the install from the `functions` directory before. (And I don't understand what happened in the local web server case then.) Many thanks.

Comment: @DougStevenson Do you want to add the answer? Or should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions will only install the modules that you've declared as dependencies in your `package.json` (and their dependencies) in the `functions` folder.  If the module doesn't show up there, you won't be able to access it directly from your code.  Be sure to run `@google-cloud/speech` from your `functions` folder, so that you can use it both during development an when deployed.

Comment: Thanks. I still do not understand how to activate `@google-cloud/speech` on the local dev server, but that is another question, I believe.

Comment: Typically a module doesn't do anything until you start writing code that accesses it.

Comment: :-) That is my experience too. I have posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471143/activating-google-speech-api-in-firebase-cli