# Activating Google Speech API in Firebase CLI?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I get this error when I try to use Google Speech from either the cmd command line (Windows 10) using `curl` or from a local Firebase server.

> "Cloud Speech API has not been used in project firebase-cli before or
>   it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/speech.googleapis.com/overview?project=firebase-cli
>   then retry"

Going to the suggested URL just gives the message:

> The API "speech.googleapis.com" doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it

The `curl` command has worked before. Login seems to work (using `Bearer` header). I have no idea why it does not work now. Did I do something before that made it work? Or is there some change to Firebase CLI/Google Speech?

EDIT: Here is the curl command that worked before. I do not think it matters here, but someone might be interested still:

```
@for /f %%i in ('gcloud auth application-default print-access-token') do @set bearer=%%i

curl -X POST ^
 -H "Authorization: Bearer %bearer%" ^
 -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" ^
 --data @request-flac.json ^
 "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:longrunningrecognize"
```

Comment: It's going to be hard to help without seeing the code/CLI command/curl call that you run.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't think it matters since it worked before, but I have added it. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: You sure that the gcloud auth step completed successfully? Does the script work from the cloud shell?

Comment: @Oliver The auth step seems to work. I can see the bearer. The error message is the same as above. (I will try the cloud shell later.)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the [Cloud Speech API quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/quickstart).  There is a button that will help you enable the API in your project.  If you don't want to do it that way:

1. Go to the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/?_ga=2.94488601.-408544781.1521660794)
2. Select the  APIs and Services option in the left menu
3. Select dashboard
4. Click Enable APIs and Services
5. Type "speech" in the search box
6. Click the "Speech API" card
7. Click Enable

This is the generalized way to enable APIs in your project.

Comment: Thanks, but the Speech API is already enabled. And i have previously used it in this project too.

Comment: I am facing the same issue