# Deploying to Firestore Cloud Functions - "Error: cannot find module"

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting this when trying to deploy functions:

```
Deployment error.
Build failed: npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "../config/myconfig" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

This is after even updating the `package.json` in my `functions` directory [as suggested by the official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies) to look like this:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "sms_sender": "file:./",
    "myconfig": "file:../config/myconfig",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"
  },
...
```

which is supposed to fix this error as seen in the stacktrace on the GCP logs:

```
A 2020-08-27T12:43:39.026Z sendMessage Could not load the function, shutting down. sendMessage
A 2020-08-27T12:43:39.020Z sendMessage     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3) sendMessage
A 2020-08-27T12:43:39.020Z sendMessage     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12) sendMessage
A 2020-08-27T12:43:39.020Z sendMessage     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32) sendMessage
A 2020-08-27T12:43:39.020Z sendMessage     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10) sendMessage
A 2020-08-27T12:43:39.019Z sendMessage     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30) sendMessage
A 2020-08-27T12:43:39.019Z sendMessage     at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/sms_sender.js:5:16) sendMessage
A 2020-08-27T12:43:39.019Z sendMessage     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18) sendMessage
A 2020-08-27T12:43:39.019Z sendMessage     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17) sendMessage
A 2020-08-27T12:43:39.019Z sendMessage     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25) sendMessage
A 2020-08-27T12:43:39.019Z sendMessage     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15) sendMessage
A 2020-08-27T12:43:39.019Z sendMessage Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '../config/myconfig' sendMessage
A 2020-08-27T12:43:39.019Z sendMessage Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies? sendMessage
A 2020-08-27T12:43:39.019Z sendMessage Provided module can't be loaded. sendMessage
```

sendMessage is my background function in index.js which imports the 'sms_sender' module:

```
exports.sendMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  ...
  // send the sendMessage
  sms_sender.sendMsg("+123567890", "hello, my friend!");
  ...
}
```

sms_sender.js:

```
const config = require('../config/myconfig');

module.exports = {
  sendMsg: async function(recipientNum, message) {
    ...
  }
}
```

project structure:

```
/project-root
    /config
        myconfig.js
    /functions
        index.js
        sms_sender.js
        package.json
    /tests
    ...
    package.json
```

I looked at this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49461423/1145905) but it was talking about an external dependency.

How should I tell Node/npm that 'myconfig' is just a local file and not really a module per se?
I tried putting in a stub 'package.json' file to /config but I still get the same `Could not install from "../config/myconfig" as it does not contain a package.json file.` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [related discussion](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/968) on the Firebase tools repo was somewhat helpful but the [most popular answer](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/968#issuecomment-460323113) (creating a tarball under the `./functions` directory) did not quite work for me.

What worked: **create a symbolic link of the root-level `./config` folder inside of `./functions`**:

```
cd functions
ln -s ../config/ config
```

This strategy avails all the files in `config` into functions modules without causing me to re-write all other parts of my app that relay on the described file/folder structure

The only other changes I had to make:

```
// functions/package.json
...
"dependencies": {
    "sms_sender": "file:./",
    "myconfig": "file:./config/",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"
  },
...
```

and

```
// sms_sender.js
const config = require('./config/myconfig');
... // everything else is as before
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you installed the package form the functions directory instead of the project directory. It works locally and creates error when you deploy it. so,

```
cd functions
npm install [your package]
```

and it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

You need to include all files you intend to require inside the `functions` directory, as only those files are packaged up and uploaded to create the source for the Cloud Function.If you move `config` into the `functions` directory you should have better luck.

Comment: Hm, I thought about it but `config` is intended to be used across the project (for environment setup code, storing secrets, etc). Doesn't that violate the principle of separation of concerns? Tucking `config` under `functions` would require restructuring a good part of my project and feels 'unnatural', a sentiment similarly expressed by https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/968#issuecomment-460323113